# Missing artifact log4j:log4j:bundle:1.2.17

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I created a dynamic web application in eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1 using menu.
After that I converted it into a maven project using
configure -> convert to maven project. Then I did
maven->Add dependency and then searched for log4j.

After adding that on hovering over the  tag
for log4j it displays Missing artifact log4j:log4j:bundle:1.2.17.
I can't update dependencies using maven. How to fix it?
Please also explain the reason for the error.

Here is the generated xml after adding log4j.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Healthcare</groupId>
<artifactId>Healthcare</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-HEALTHCARE</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: [First why did you changed the default source folder location? The default is `src/main/java` and for webapp `src/main/webapp`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Apart from that a bundle for log4j does not exist on Maven Central just remove the `<type>bundle</type>` from your dependency, cause in Maven Central only a jar is available.

Comment: well khmarbaise have right with the remove of the type, i do in the pom.xml editor change the type from bundle to jar like i post in my answer :)

Answer (score 6):

[First why did you changed the default source folder location? The default is `src/main/java` and for webapp `src/main/webapp`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Apart from that a bundle for log4j does not exist on Maven Central just remove the `<type>bundle</type>` from your dependency, cause in Maven Central only a jar is available.

Answer (score 3):

I always do the following trick:

In the dependencies management i edit the dependencies properties (select the dependencies with problem and click on properties button) changing the type from bundled to jar and that fixs the problem.

Well i hope that this solution work for you :) regards,

Answer (score 1):

I too played with all the options provided above but it did not helped. By updating Maven dependencies forcefully my issue got resolved.

1. Go to project >> Maven >> Update Project

select the project and click OK.

Project will automatically try to download required jar but if still you are getting same error then do below step.

2. Go to project >> Maven >> Update Project >> check in the checkbox 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases'

select the project and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the dependencies  are  correct or if it is missing.

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default (and the common usage), Maven would consume jars as a dependency. Just change the bundle to jar in your `pom.xml` file in the given dependency which is giving you an error.